# Does calling a protocol method pass program flow control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, ios, custom-protocol

I know this is quite possibly a lame question, but I've pulled three consecutive all-nighters and I'm very blurry. And I'm new to Objective C and Cocoa Touch.

I've created a class that provides a delegate method. I'll use simplified example code since the specifics aren't important. The header file looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol UsernameCheckerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)didTheRequestedThing:(BOOL)wasSuccessful;
@end

@interface TheDelegateClass : NSObject {
    id <TheDelegateClassDelegate> tdcDelegate;
}

@property (assign) id <TheDelegateClassDelegate> tdcDelegate;

- (void)methodThatDoesSomething:(int)theValue;

@end
```

And the source file looks like this:

```
#import "TheDelegateClass.h"

@implementation TheDelegateClass

@synthesize tdcDelegate;

- (void)methodThatDoesSomething:(int)theValue {
    if (theValue > 10) {
        [[self tdcDelegate] didTheRequestedThing:NO];
        // POINT A
    }

    // POINT B
    int newValue = theValue * 10;
    NSString *subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey Bob, %i", newValue];
    // Some more stuff here, send an email or something, whatever

    [[self tdcDelegate] didTheRequestedThing:YES];
    // POINT C
}

@end
```

Here's my question: if **theValue** is in fact greater than 10 and the line above POINT A runs, does program flow control pass out of this method (and back to the **didTheRequestedThing** delegate method in the object that called this) or does flow continue on through POINT B to POINT C?

I'm hoping for the former because I can simplify the heck out of my code, currently an unpleasant mess of deeply nested ifs and elses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the -didTheRequestedThing: method returns, control flow returns back to your POINT A and continues on to POINT B and POINT C. Delegate method calls are exactly like any other method call. If you want to avoid executing the rest of the method after the delegate call, just stick a call to `return` where your // POINT A comment is.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed as much but figured I'd check. The return is pretty obious, d'oh!

Comment: A simple way to verify that this is true is to ask yourself, if the control flow doesn't come back to POINT A, then where does it go? There's nothing in your listed code to instruct it to exit `-methodThatDoesSomething:` after calling the delegate.

Comment: Now that I've actually slept a night I'm embarrassed by the question. Alas. :)